# saferpay intergration on businesscatalyst

Tags: .net

How do I integrate Saferpay controls? I'm finding it hard to test and get views on Saferpay. I'm just a newbie at this; it would be much appreciated if someone could help me. Finding answers to my question is really hard, their tutorials are in Russian and I can't even understand any words in their video.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the specification is also available in German and I suppose in English, as well. They contain examples on how to implement their different solutions for .NET, JSP and HTTP for every other environment.

Just mail `integration [AT] saferpay.com` or `support [AT] saferpay.com` to get your PDFs.